# Spring MVC jsp page mapping using class configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I'm trying to run a Spring MVC example application and got a sock with the JSP pages mapping. I struggled a full day with this problem but I didn't find any solution...

**Project Structure**

[image]

**The pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ro.telacad</groupId>
    <artifactId>java4c5e2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>java4c5e2 Maven Webapp</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>java4c5e2</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                            <port>8080</port>
                            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                        </connector>
                    </connectors>
                    <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>8005</stopPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**This is the Dispatcher Servlet Initializer**

```
public class MyAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses(){
        return new Class[]{ProjectConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses(){
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings(){
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

**This is the WebConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"app","config","controllers"})
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer){
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);

        return resolver;
    }
}
```

**This is the ProjectConfig**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"app","config","controllers"},
        excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = EnableWebMvc.class)})
public class ProjectConfig {
}
```

**And the Main controller** which should redirect to the home.jsp page when the /home endpoint is called (but it does not).

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homeAction(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("nume", "John");
        System.out.println("mue");
        return "home";
    }

}
```

I must say that I have no issues going onto the `index.jsp` page.But when I try calling the /home endpoint it returns "HTTP ERROR: 404" not found...

[image]

I'm not sure if I should add something in to the the web.xml file, having in consideration that I'm trying to do a Java class configuration.

**The web.xml file**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

[You can find the project's source code here](https://github.com/laurentiuiordache/java-4-spring/tree/master/course%205/java4c5e2)

Comment: Can you upload your project in any where ?

Comment: Yes, I just updated the post

Comment: Check my github project I mentioned in my answer

Comment: Well, I checked it. It works well, but when I copy-paste my source code into the project it works as well... I think I messed it up when I created the project from web-app maven archetype. That seems to be the only difference. Anyhow, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code, modified your code. And now everything working fine.

My project structure is [image]

`pom.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.avijit</groupId>
    <artifactId>overflow</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is the Configuration class where I modified a little

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.avijit")
public class HelloWorldConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Initializer class is

```
public class HelloWorldInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { HelloWorldConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

My controller class is

```
Controller
    public class HelloWorldController {
        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String sayHello(ModelMap model) {
            model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World from Spring 4 MVC");
            return "welcome";
        }
    }
```

jsp page is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
                 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
            <title>HelloWorld page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        Greeting : ${greeting}
        </body>
        </html>
```

Here my github [https://github.com/AaviJit/stackoverflowtest](http://link)

Answer (score 1):

First change version of

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Because version problem is a silly problem in spring. 
Second thing change

```
 resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views");
```

to

```
 resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
```

And others looks fine

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these mistakes. Unfortunately the problem remains, I still can't access the /home endpoint

Comment: Please change version of  `<artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId><version>3.1.0</version>` to  `<version>4.0.1</version>`

Comment: It didn't worked. I don't think the problem is related to dependencies. The application starts in jetty container with no problems. There I can access just the `index.json` page. I think is something related to the view mapping but I can't think about any useful solution.

Comment: I think if you try xml configuration you will  face less issue

Comment: Yes, I know. I found a lot of examples based on xml configuration. But the scope of this example is to learn a way to configure using classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your HelloWorldInitializer class like bellow :

```
    @Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { HelloWorldConfiguration.class };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}
```